# NameError в модульном тесте

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Почему выдаёт ошибку?
Нужно проверить, что `а * b = x`.

```
import unittest

class TestFactorization(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1 (self):
        x = 77
        a, b = factorize(x)
        self.assertEqual(test_1(a*b), x)
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуста, всю ошибку, а не только ее название. Из действительно очевидного - `factorize` не импортирован.

Comment: Поддержу Нужен полный вывод интерпритатора - Traceback

Comment: Спасибо, ребят, разобралась. Проблема была в "test_1 внутри assertEqual" .  Т.к. задание учебное, factorize импортировать не нужно было.

Comment: @insolor, если хотите, напишите это в ответ (не коммент), я приму его.

Comment: @maps добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Отсутствует функция `factorize`. Если это функция из другого модуля, то нужно эту функцию импортировать из него, иначе будет `NameError`.
2. В `assertEqual` вызывается несуществующая функция `test_1` - это не метод `test_1` тестового объекта `TestFactorization`, т.к. вызывается не от `self`. Если функция `factorize` разбивает число на два множителя, то нужно просто перемножить эти два числа и сравнить с исходным: `self.assertEqual(a*b, x)`